# How to reduce the size of Flutter .aab file?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-app-bundle

I made a calculator app using flutter and when I generated the `.aab` file, it came out to be `16 MB`! How do I reduce the size of my `.aab` file?

Comment: Note that my app does not have any kind of photos or assets attached to it.

Comment: use the following link to ```reducing app size``` regarding to the flutter official documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#reducing-app-size

Comment: The .aab size will be reduced after your application is deployed on the Play Store. My .abb file size was around 17.5MB but after deployment i got 6.4M in size. see your self https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.letesend.compassiontv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding to the flutter official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#reducing-app-size).

#### Reducing app size

When building a release version of your app, consider using the `--split-debug-info` tag. This tag can dramatically reduce code size. For an example of using this tag, [see Obfuscating Dart code](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate).

Some other things you can do to make your app smaller are:

- Remove unused resources
- Minimize resource imported from libraries
- Compress PNG and JPEG files

#### Build the .abb

1. Clean your project

```sh
flutter clean
```

2. Build an appbundle using the --split-debug-info tag

```sh
 flutter build appbundle --obfuscate  --split-debug-info=<the-path>
```

Note the `<the-path>`, a location where your app-release.aab will be copied.

---

Output

```sh
 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             94,8s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab (17.5MB).
```

Note that the final size of my `app-release.aab` is `17.5MB`.

---

For more details recarding to deploy flutter android app [read the official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android).

#### Download size

After deploying my Flutter app to `playstore`, I was surprised to see that the `download size` is finally `6.4M`.

[image]

This is a full app in production, not just a default flutter counter app. [You can try it on playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.letesend.compassiontv).